# How to set variable in Java projection?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, projection

I have the following projection in my Java (Spring Boot) app:

```
public interface DemoProjection {
    UUID getUuid();
    String getName();
    String getSurname();

    String getLabel();
    void setLabel(String label);
```

I want to set this `label` field in my service:

```
public DemoProjection findAByUuid(UUID uuid) {
        // returns a single record
        final DemoProjection demo =  demoRepository.findAByUuid(uuid);
        final String label = String.format(
                "Name: %s%nSurnamame Surname: %s",
                demo.geteName(),
                demo.getSurname());

        // ! this line throws error
        demo.setLabel(label);
        return demo;
    }
```

`demo.setLabel(label);` throws error: *"cannot set projection A TupleBackedMap cannot be modified."*

So, how can I set `label` field in the projection?

Comment: What does `demoRepository.findAll()` return?

Comment: It returns projection of course

Comment: `findAll()` seems to return more than 1 object and it is mapped to touples and not into just 1 single object. That means you can't access directly a field like you do with having a single object.
You should re-think your naming conventions.

Comment: No, it returns exactly one single element in `DemoProjection` type.Sorry, I mistyped its name.

Comment: Set a breakpoint and stop the code on `setLabel()`. You will see that your object might look different. MAybe not the main object itself but the label attribute.

Comment: my demo variable seems `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap@20bdc2ce`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't actually do that. Spring Data uses proxies and AOP to bind the query result to your projection interface, and since it's an interface you can't change that in a magical way. I would suggest creating a model/dto and map your projection values there:

```
public class DemoDto {
  private String uuid;
  private String name;
  private String surname;
  
  //getters and setters ommited for brevity
}
```

You can create a DemoDto object with your desired values.

In alternative, you can use a projection class instead of a projection interface. Check spring docs on how to do that :)

Comment: I am not sure if I can use projection class rather than interface. SO, what about posting an example?

Comment: you can have example here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-projections#class-based-projections

Answer (score 1):

Just create a default method in your DemoProjection interface to return getLabel formatted as you wish:

```
public interface DemoProjection {
  UUID getUuid();
  String getName();
  String getSurname();

  default String getLabel() {
      return String.format(
            "Name: %s%nSurnamame Surname: %s",
            geteName(),
            getSurname());
  }
}
```

this is required as you can't set a Projection after it has been created by JPA but since you only need formatting there is no need to set anything - default method does the trick.

Comment: Thanks for helps. Actually I exactly used this approach, but I want to move this logic to service. In this case, how can I fix the problem?

Comment: then move the getLabel method into a service that accepts Projection as a parameter and return formatted label.

Comment: ANy example code please? I may use your approach and select your answer if it is better approach

Comment: we are not here to write code for you, it is YOU who should provide code of what you have tried and how it didn't work for every single question you have. Then we will happily correct. With such a simple request as moving a method to another class you are just being lazy